# Why do we recite Oseh Shalom at end of Amiday

Tags: tefilla

Elokai Ntsor is a private meditation yet it ends with Oseh Shalom-V'imru Amen. Imru Amen is plural and the meditation is private implying some kind of mixed message. Could it be that since everyone is saying albeit their own message that it is still plural as everyone is doing it? Please clarify thanks

Comment: I never considered that it was part of Elohai Netzor. Does it not come afterward?

Comment: Is your question why we say Oseh Shalom at the end of Elokai Netzor, or why we say v’imru in the plural?